# Trying to get better at understand sql queries

Tags: sql

I'm a new developer in a corporate IT group.  I feel completely lost looking at alot of the sql that's written in our code.  There are many queries that are literally hundreds of lines long.  Here's an example of a "smaller" one (the table/field names have been modified, but the structure is the same).  Do I just suck at this or is it really difficult to understand?  How would you approach rewriting it to be more manageable/understandable?

```
SELECT pd.commission_header_id COMMISSION_HEADER_ID
          ,pd.sales_rep_id DIRECT_SALESREP_ID
          ,pd.org_id ORG_ID
          ,LEAST(100, innview.spilt_percent)  SPLIT_PCT
          ,pd.source SOURCE
          ,pd.application APPLICATION
          ,pd.plan PLANE
          ,pd.pay_freq pay_freq
          ,pd.emp_app_count EMP_APP_COUNT
          ,pd.client_name CLIENT_NAME
          ,pd.fed_id FED_ID
          ,pd.off_nbr OFF_NBR
          ,pd.payroll_num payroll_num
          ,TO_DATE(pd.product_start_date,'DD-MON-YY') PRODUCT_START_DATE
          ,pd.loss_date LOSS_DATE
          ,pd.acquisitions_ind ACQUISITIONS_IND
          ,pd.source_of_business SOURCE_OF_BUSINESS
          ,pd.prev_br_clt_nbr PREV_BR_CLT_NBR
          ,pd.previous_method PREVIOUS_METHOD
          ,pd.natl_acct_number NATL_ACCT_NUMBER
          ,pd.product_name PRODUCT_NAME
          ,pd.lost_reason LOST_REASON
          ,pd.client_id CLIENT_ID
          ,pd.lead_nbr LEAD_NBR
          ,pd.processed_date PROCESSED_DATE
          ,pd.rep_type REP_TYPE
          ,pd.order_number ORDER_NUMBER 
          ,pd.conversion_type CONVERSION_TYPE
          ,SUBSTR(original_billing_info,1,INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,1)-1) BILLING_APPLICATION
          ,SUBSTR(original_billing_info,INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,1)+1,INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,2)-INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,1)-1) BILLING_CODE
          ,SUBSTR(original_billing_info,INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,2)+1,INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,3)-INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,2)-1) BILLING_PROD_GRP_NM
          ,SUBSTR(original_billing_info,INSTR(original_billing_info,'|',1,3)+1) BILLING_FIELD_FOR_CHRGS
          ,SUBSTR(original_discount_info,1,INSTR(original_discount_info,'|',1,1)-1) DISCOUNT_APPLICATION
          ,SUBSTR(original_discount_info,INSTR(original_discount_info,'|',1,1)+1,INSTR(original_discount_info,'|',1,2)-INSTR(original_discount_info,'|',1,1)-1) DISCOUNT_CODE
          ,CASE WHEN (NVL(innview.trans,0)) = 0 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE ( NVL(innview.comm,0)) / ( NVL(innview.trans,0)) 
                 END ORIGINAL_COMM_PCT 
          ,pd.record_type RECORD_TYPE 
          ,innview.trans PAR_SUM 
          ,NVL(ocp.oic_clients_pk, pxmis.oic_client_products_pk_seq.nextval) CLIENT_PRODUCT_ID
          ,pd.associated_with ASSOCIATED_WITH_ID
          ,pd.refferal_sale refferal_sale
          ,pd.parent_client_nbr PARENT_CLIENT_NBR
      FROM pxmis.pd_commissions pd
      JOIN pxmis.oic_lookback_months olm ON (pd.application = olm.application
                                           AND pd.plan = olm.plan) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN pxmis.oic_client_products ocp ON (pd.off_nbr = ocp.off_nbr
                                             AND pd.payroll_num = ocp.payroll_num
                                             AND pd.application = ocp.application
                                             AND pd.plan = ocp.plan
                                             AND pd.sales_rep_id = ocp.direct_salesrep_id
                                             AND pd.source = ocp.source
                                             AND ocp.record_type in (:1,:2)
                                             AND NVL(pd.refferal_sale,'NON REF') = NVL(ocp.refferal_sale,'NON REF'))
       JOIN (SELECT SUM(NVL(transaction_amount,0)) as trans 
                   ,SUM(commission_amount) as comm 
                   ,SUM(pd2.oic_split_percent) as spilt_percent 
                   ,pd2.application as application 
                   ,pd2.plan       as code 
                   ,pd2.sales_rep_id    as sales_rep_id 
                   ,pd2.payroll_num as client_nbr 
                   ,LPAD(pd2.off_nbr,4,0) as off_nbr 
               FROM pxmis.pd_commissions pd2 
               JOIN pxmis.oic_lookback_months olm2 ON (pd2.application = olm2.application 
                                                   AND pd2.plan = olm2.plan) 
               WHERE CASE WHEN (pd2.record_type IN ('SAPBA','ASAPBA')) 
                          THEN pd2.SUB_RECORD_TYPE 
                          ELSE 'Eligible' 
                          END = 'Eligible' 
                 AND pd2.record_type IN ('SDBDA', 'ASDBDA', 
                                          decode(:3,'CHCST','SAPBA',NULL), 
                                          decode(:4,'CHCST','ASAPBA',NULL), 
                                          'SAPBP','ASAPBP') 
                AND pd2.processed_date BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(:5,(olm2.lookback_months_high - 1) * -1) AND ADD_MONTHS(:6, (olm2.lookback_months_low - 2) * -1) - 1 
                and :7 between olm2.effective_start_date and olm2.effective_end_date 
                and olm2.function_type = :8 
            GROUP BY pd2.application  
                  ,pd2.plan  
                  ,pd2.sales_rep_id  
                  ,pd2.payroll_num  
                  ,LPAD(pd2.off_nbr,4,0)) innview on (innview.application = pd.application 
                                              AND innview.code = pd.plan 
                                              AND innview.sales_rep_id = pd.sales_rep_id 
                                              AND innview.client_nbr = pd.payroll_num 
                                              AND innview.off_nbr = LPAD(pd.off_nbr,4,0)) 
     WHERE :9 BETWEEN olm.effective_start_date AND olm.effective_end_date
       AND pd.sales_rep_id <> -3
       AND pd.record_type IN ('SAPBP','ASAPBP')
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'X'
                        FROM pxmis.pd_commissions pd3
                       WHERE pd3.application = pd.application
                         AND pd3.plan = pd.plan
                         AND pd3.sales_rep_id = pd.sales_rep_id
                         AND pd3.payroll_num = pd.payroll_num
                         AND (pd3.record_type in ('CHCST','ACHCST') 
                              or ( pd3.record_type = 'SAPBA' 
                                   and pd3.sub_record_type = 'Chargeback')))
       AND pd.commission_header_id = (SELECT MAX(pd4.commission_header_id)
                                    FROM pxmis.pd_commissions pd4
                                   WHERE pd4.application = pd.application
                                     AND pd4.plan = pd.plan
                                     AND pd4.sales_rep_id = pd.sales_rep_id
                                     AND pd4.payroll_num = pd.payroll_num
                                     AND pd4.record_type = pd.record_type) 
       AND olm.function_type = :10
       AND pd.processed_date BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(:11,(olm.lookback_months_high - 1) * -1) AND ADD_MONTHS(:12, (olm.lookback_months_low - 2) * -1) - 1
       AND pd.source = :13 
       AND pay_freq IS NOT NULL
       AND pd.core_conversion_revenue IS NULL;
```

Comment: Nice try, but we wont do your work re-writing the query for you.

Comment: It always looks complicated the first time, instead of trying to understand the query spend some time on understanding tables involved and their relationships in the database, Query designer is a good place to start, Good luck!

Comment: It takes practice and experience.  You don't ask a 2nd grader to read War and Peace.  Start by learning how basic queries work.  Break down the bigger queries into smaller ones and understand how they work.  If you have _specific_ questions about the query above, ask your colleagues or post here (after researching of course :) )

Comment: I wouldn't, unless I really know what I'm doing. This query doesn't seem to be that complicated (though it is quite long), and is well formatted. My best advice to you is to read a good sql tutorial, preferably one that is related to the rdbms you are using, and practice writing sql statements yourself, until you feel you can handle reading statements like this without fear.

Comment: And I wouldn't try to rewrite it to be "more manageable/understandable" until you _completely_ understand what it's doing.  Many queries are performance tuned in a way that makes it less understandable _until you understand what it's doing_.

Comment: @jarlh I'm not asking you to rewrite it.  It's not a task of mine to rewrite it either.  I'm just trying to learn and understand the perspective of more experienced devs.  That's the whole point of this site, no?

Comment: First Divide the whole query into smaller parts, then execute each query and understand result. then you can take 2 tables query gradually.
Once you understand inner queries, it will be easier to understand larger queries :)

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote: (Due to my reputation I can not make comments:)*

This is my first time answering. Hopefully it will help.
I do not know if it might help, but most of the SQL script (maybe all of it), can be rewritten in other languages. For example you can use *JOINS* in C# .NET LINQ.

But a way I usually separate the SQL script, is to look for the keywords and see what they do. Do not confuse the big letters from the small ones.

The *SELECT* function selects all of the datas.

The *TO_DATE* function says that it will convert the a string to date (source: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

The *LEAST* function returns the smallest number between the variables you have as parameters (Source: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/least.php)

You can do this for every function, and try and grasp what the script does.

I think you could end the script here: `FROM pxmis.pd_commissions pd`

Also I have seen that you do a *JOIN*.
Here you could properly make a new script and run that code.

Right now I might not be able to make it more readable. (Mostly because I work with .NET C# linqs).

Again hopefully it helped in some way.